# Uncertainty with Symlinks

Tags: ubuntu, python, directory, symlink

I've done a quick search but I can't find anything specific about this scenario:

Let's say I have a directory (let's ignore the path) and call it A. Now, I create a symlink to directory A called S. We should now have:

```
S -> A
```

If I then have another directory, let's say B and do something along the lines of:

```
cp -r B/ A/
```

will the symlink persist, or would this break it? Let's say instead of using the bash command, I use the python distutils.dir_utils.copytree(B, A), would the symlink S still point to A? Is A still A or has it become B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test this from the command line fairly easily:

```
# set up test
mkdir A
mkdir B
echo "this is A" > A/test.txt
echo "this is B" > B/test.txt
echo "this is A" > A/old.txt
echo "this is B" > B/new.txt

# contents of A change on copy
ln -s A S
cat S/test.txt
cp -r B/ A/
cat S/test.txt
cat A/test.txt

# S still points to A
ls -l S/
ls -l A/
ls -l B/
```

As you will be able to see files from B that overwrite files from A will have an impact on both A and S. However as you are copying the files from A with names unique between A and B will remain because **S is still pointing to A but A has changed**.

Symbolic links point to a path. For example if you remove A and leave S, S still refers to A which no longer exists:

```
rm -rf A/
ls -l S/
```

If you were to now create a text file with the called A, S would point to this text file as it is still pointing to the path A. As Kusalananda and G-Man say nothing you do to A will affect S. Or more explicitly **nothing you do to A will affect the fact that S points to A**.

```
echo "new text file" > A
cat S
```

Comment: I see, thank you for the detailed response.

Comment: "S will no longer be a directory". In fact, `S` was _never_ a directory. It was, and remains, a symbolic link. Nothing that you do to the path pointed to by the symbolic link `S` affects the symbolic link itself. G-Man is 100% correct in this. You have the wrong concept of what a symbolic link is.

Comment: @Kusalananda you are correct, I worded that in a very misleading way. I edited the answer, although I'm sure it could still be edited further to be more explicit and correct. You are also right that G-Man is correct, I do however believe his answer could also be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

The symbolic link `S` points to `A` by means of the path to `A`.  Copying files into `A` (which is what your command is doing) will not affect this link.

If you, for whatever reason, renamed or removed `A`, then the symbolic link `S` would be broken and unusable. If you then created something else, possibly a new directory, called `A` in the same location as the old `A`, then `S` would be a symbolic link to that thing instead.

Note that the symbolic link `S` is totally separate from the directory `A`.  `S` in itself does not care whether `A` exists or not, or whether it is a file, a directory or something else.  Anything you do to `A` will *not* affect `S`.

The act of dereferencing the symbolic link `S` (i.e. using it, for example by doing `ls S`) will have different outcomes depending on what `A` is (if it exists, if it's a directory, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for the brief answer. It also answered my question but I decide to go with jTables' answer as it was more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you had a file called `S.txt` (in some separate directory) that said

> The information that you’re looking for is in directory `A`.

It wouldn’t be affected by anything you did to directory `A`.

Symbolic links are very much like this. 
The symbolic link won’t be affected by anything you do to its target.